# How to sort spreadsheet by date+time column but with a modified hour column?

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet generated by a Google form and it produces a standard spreadsheet with a full timestamp column, that is two hours behind, and an hour column (hh:mm am/pm) that the user fills in manually.

I need to apply the hour that the user has filled to the date column and sort the result, displaying in a different sheet and updating values as more forms are submitted.

Here's a copy of [the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KVXVMGTcGsE2-OJvoZXQTC9Q-FzCq5MNvfglnqFhWCI/).

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer

```
=Array_Constrain(ArrayFormula(INT(A2:A)+(H2:H)),COUNT(A2:A),1)
```

## Explanation

- `INT(A2:A)` removes the time part of the timestamp.
- `+H2:H` adds the time captured by the respondent
- `Array_Formula()` makes that the inner functions returns array of values.
- `COUNT(A2:A)` counts the number of form submissions.
- `Array_Constrain()` limits the results the number of form submissions.